# How do you emulate a game pad input to an Android device?

Tags: android, input, gamepad-api

So I'm trying to create an application that can emulate a gamepad on device, kinda like how vjoy programs work for windows with a HID input emulator, but I can't figure out how, the best idea I've tried so far is to use a rubber ducky to emulate it physically. How can I simulate inputs to the android controller API otherwise?